# I know for myself or I know to myself

Tags: phrases

Which is best when describing what you already realize within yourself.

To give context, I was self-reflecting during this time. I was going to say that:

> I know to/for myself that I was having some problems about my lack of self-discipline and time management.

Comment: Perhaps "I know that..." You don't need to elborate on that: we know what "I" means, but perhaps you have a context that you can show.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To give context, I was self-reflecting during this time. I was going to say that: "I know to/for myself that I was having some problems about my lack of self-discipline and time management."

Comment: Perhaps "I recognised that I was having problems with..."

Comment: I agree. That's a better way to put it! Thanks @WeatherVane

Comment: If you mean that you "knew" something without needing to be ***told***, perhaps you knew it ***instinctively, intuitively.*** But if you had to spend time and effort ***figuring it out for yourself***, that's a different situation - within which you could say you're ***self-taught***, but I can't think of a single-word adjective to refer to *knowledge accumulated **by one's own observation,** experiment, and thinking, **not** gained through the experience and words of others*. There probably isn't much such knowledge anyway, so it might not need a name.

Comment: It's not clear - did you know at the time, or do you know now but didn't know then? That would affect what's the most idiomatic way of expresssing it. I also think it might depend on the context: are you contrasting it with something else, and if so what (things you didn't know, things other people know, things you worked out later.) Having said that "for myself" doesn't sound bad ("I knew for myself" is maybe more common).

Comment: "I know, for myself, **that x**" works. I know "to myself" simply does not work in your context.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat formal phrase would be

> *I know it to be true **of myself** that ...*

or somewhat less formally

> *I can say **of myself** that ...*